# Dynamically disable crittercism reporting in Android

Tags: android, crittercism

Is there a way to dynamically disable reporting by Crittercism?
I saw

> setOptOutStatus

method but I am not sure if this is for disabling all reporting by Crittercism?
Also, could anyone please let me know where I can download the API docs for Crittercism?